# I am Trying to Insert info to Mysql Database but 'The method or operation is not implemented.' this error doesnt let me

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to Insert datas from Textboxes to MySql Database with Button Click, here is the code

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password =");

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                                    
                conn.Open();
                string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO library.addbook(bookId, bookName, bookType, authors, publisher) Value(" + bookID.Text + bookName.Text + bookType.Text + author.Text + publisher.Text + "','" + conn +")";            
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();               
        }
```

But when it is Run

> "System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not
> implemented.'" this error pop-up in;
>
> ` internal int ExecuteNonQuery()
>
> ```
>    {
>         throw  new NotImplementedException();
>     }`
> ```

Comment: Did you implement that `MySqlCommand` class yourself? If you use the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand` class in [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data) then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't have defined somewhere a MySqlCommand class hiding the one provided by the MySqlConnector then your code needs a lot of fixes.

See the comments below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                  
    // The insert into query requires the list of fields to insert and,  
    // for each field, the value to use _separated by a comma_

    // The query should also be parameterized, or in other words you don't
    // concatenate the values from your textboxes directly in the query
    // This is the only correct way to avoid syntax errors and sql Injection 
    // So we just put placeholders (@xxxxxx) where you have a value to add                 
    string insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO library.addbook(bookId, bookName, bookType, authors, publisher) 
              Values (@bookID, @bookName, @bookType, @author, @publisher)";            

    // The connection is a disposable object. As such you should use the using
    // statement to be sure to close and dispose at the exit of the using block
    // even in case of exceptions. Do not keep a global connection object hoping to have more performances.  
    // There is a thing called connection pooling for this 
    // Note also that your connectionstring should be stored in the config file
    // so it can be changed easily and not hard coded in every point where
    // you need it.
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(GetTheConnectionStringFromConfigFile())
    {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

        // The parameters should be added for each of the placeholders 
        // present in the insertQuery text and each should be defined
        // with the correct data type
        command.Parameters.Add("@bookID", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = bookID.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@bookName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bookName.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@bookType", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bookType.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@author", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = author.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@publisher", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = publisher.Text;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

There are also other points to consider. If the bookID is an integer, you should check if the user has typed effectively a number with Int32.TryParse.
Not sure if the bookType is a text or some identifying number. In the later case you should use the correct datatype for the parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in this way ı have another issue. I'm so new for this :) . I didnt find a way get rid of this problem. @Steve

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Library Managemnt System C:\Users\Nuray YILDIRIM\source\repos\Library Managemnt System\Library Managemnt System\Forms\addbook.cs 32 Active

Comment: There is something not quite right in your _using_ directives at the top of that file _addbook.cs_ You should have a using _MySql.Data.MySqlClient_ and you need to have a reference in your project to the _MySql.Data.dll_ Unless there is some other part of your code that redefines MySqlCommand to something different.  Try to _MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand command = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(....);_ Does it work?

Comment: Seems like everything is right place. Yes there is  ' using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;' on the top. And no, actually I cannot see the 'MySqlCommand' is defines other thing but this  'MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);'. I did try yours but nothing is changed. @Steve

Comment: Sorry, but I have no more ideas. What framework/net version are you using in your project/solutions settings? What is the version of the MySql.Data.dll referenced by the project?

Comment: Net 5.0, MySql.Data.dll = 8.0.29. Thanks a lot mate. Your ideas did really helped me anyway :) @Steve